# Как выводить данные из таблицы в порядке от новых к старым

Tags: php, laravel

У меня сейчас выводится таблица, начиная со старых и к новым, а нужно наоборот.

***Контроллер***:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Histori;

class HistoryController extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    $history = Histori::all();

    return view('admin.pages.history', compact('history'));
  }
}
```

***Шаблон***:

```html
@extends('admin.layouts.app_admin')

@section('title','все пользователи')  

@section('content')
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead style="color: black">
    <tr style="color: black">
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Дата</th>
      <th>Действия</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  @foreach($history as $his)
    <tr>
      <th style="color: black">{{$loop->index+1}}</th>
      <th>{{$his->data}}</th>
      <th>{{$his->action}}</th>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
@endsection
```

Comment: Метод - orderBy поможет вам отсортировать результат по столбцу, по дате изменения, по дате добавления и по другим колонкам. Изучите документацию. Ответ - `Histori::orderByDesc('id')->get()`

Comment: Впишите код как ответ я отмечу галочку

Comment: Мой ответ максимум на комментарий тянет, пусть кто-нибудь другой подробно опишет или просто кусок данного метода из документации переведёт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function index(Histori $histori)
{
  $history = $histori->orderBy('data', desc)->get();

  return view('admin.pages.history', compact('history'));
}
```

Подробнее о методе `orderBy`: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#chunking-results

И, пожалуйста, не брезгуйте чистотой кода и правописанием, ведь даже при всем желании помочь, понять суть возникшей проблемы достаточно тяжело.

Самый актуальный сборник рекомендаций по чистоте PHP кода: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/